# How to addStep in @wdio/allure-reporter with wdio mocha

Tags: mocha.js, allure, wdio-v4

I am not able to add a new step.

I need to add a step in my report for a negative scenario. I had referred the documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/@wdio/allure-reporter.

```
const { addFeature } = require('@wdio/allure-reporter').default

describe('Suite', () => {
    it('Case', () => {
        addStep('**exceptions**')
    })
})
```

I am using allure report 5.3.4

```
"@wdio/allure-reporter": "^5.3.4",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out

```
import AllureReporter from '@wdio/allure-reporter';

it('*************  *********', async () => {

    await AllureReporter.addStep(`The ${ele} does not exist ..... `)
    await AllureReporter.addStep(`The ${ele} does not exist ..... `)

})
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on your query i guess you need to add two things first the startStep Method and then try to add your addStep method.

```
const { addFeature } = require('@wdio/allure-reporter').default

describe('Suite', () => {
    it('Case', () => {
        startStep('*** negative test starts here *****')
        addStep('**exceptions**') 
        endStep("passed") //Accepts two values passed or failed
    })
})
```